# Solve $(2+\sqrt{3})^{x/2}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{x/2}=2^x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

How to solve $(2+\sqrt{3})^{x/2}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{x/2}=2^x$ for $x$?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, yet, but $(2+\sqrt{3})$ and $(2-\sqrt{3})$ are multiplicative inverses. Probably it simplifies some things.

Comment: $x=2$ works (by plug/chug)...

Comment: Let $a=(2+\sqrt{3}),\ \frac{1}{a}=(2-\sqrt{3})$, we have $a^{x/2}+\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{x/2}=\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{x/2}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply by $(2+\sqrt 3)^{x/2}$ we get

$$(2+\sqrt 3)^x+1=2^x(2+\sqrt 3)^{x/2}=2^x((\sqrt2+\sqrt6)/2)^x=(\sqrt2+\sqrt 6)^x$$
but $(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 6)>(2+\sqrt 3)$ then if the equality is true for $x=2$ it can't be true for $x\ne2$.

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: Less clean, but maybe easier to right the RHS as $(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^x$ if you don't see the equivalence you saw right away

Answer (score 1):

So, by inspection, $x=2$ is a solution. It remains to show that there are no others. Since $2-\sqrt{3}<1$, for large $x$, we can essentially ignore this term, so some growth rate arguments show that one side grows faster than the other and there are no more solutions, but I'm not sure how to make this rigorous.

Comment: exactly where I was going with this once I saw $x=2$...

Comment: Quick sketch of the graph of both sides shows there can be only one solution.  Probably prove it taking derivatives.

Comment: It's easy to see from the graphs that there are no solutions $x<0$, if that's what you mean.